# Append form data to an excel file stored locally using Tampermonkey script

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

I have a use-case wherein there's some data on a webpage. I need some information present on that page along with some inputs from the user accessing that page. I have created a Tamper Monkey script which will create a button on the page. On button click, I will append a form on that page with all the required fields. 
On submitting that form, I want to store the information in an excel in a shared drive which is accessible on all the user machines. I am not able to figure out how to send this information to a local file.

Comment: Can't.  You can send data to a Google doc via their API, or write a small webapp to run on your machine that updates the spreadsheet.

Comment: @BrockAdams Thanks. I'll probably add it to an eternally hosted form then and fetch the data from there.